# I would like my code to only show 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code written, and when I execute it, it shows up to 10 decimal places. I was wondering if there was a way to remove the excess decimal places.

Now, I have tried this:

price= price.tofixed(2);

but this does not seem to work, and I don't understand why.

```
<script>
var weight = parseFloat(prompt("weight in lbs", "10"));
weight = weight.toFixed(2);
var price;
price= price.tofixed(2);


// writes down the volumes of triangles-->
document.write("<p>the weight is  : "+weight+"</p>");

</script>

<script>
// else if statements which will calculate the price of the shipping -->
if(weight <= 2) price=weight*1.10;
else if (weight>=2 && weight<=6) price=weight*2.20;
else if(weight>6 && weight<=10) price=weight*3.70;
else if(weight>10) price=weight*3.80;

document.write("<p>the price of the item's shipping is  "+price+"</p>");
</script>
  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is typo here. Just change to this `price= price.toFixed(2);`

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the value to be formatted like a currency amount you can use the [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) like this:

```
document.write("<p>the price of the item's shipping is  "+ 
  new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).format(price) +
"</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `price.toFixed` after `price` has been assigned. e.g.:

```
else if(weight>10) price=weight*3.80;

price = price.toFixed(2);    

document.write("<p>the price of the item's shipping is  "+price+"</p>");
```

Comment: `tofixed` should be [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).